# Как добавить путь к подключаемым файлам (include) в QBS

Tags: qt, qbs

Здравствуйте создал проект QBS для микроконтроллера не могу подключить пути к стандартным библиотекам ((

```
   Project{
    name: "qbs_avr"


Product {
        name: "micro"
        type: ["elf","hex","comp"]
       Group {
            name: "ci"
            files: ["*.c"]
            fileTags: ['c']

        }
        Group {
            name: "header"
            files: ["*.h"]
            fileTags: ['h']

        }

        Rule {
            inputs: ["c"]
            Artifact {

                filePath: 'obj/' + input.fileName + '.o'  //'.obj/' + qbs.getHash(input.baseDir) + '/' + input.fileName + '.o'
                fileTags: ['obj']
            }
            prepare: {
                var args = [];
                args.push("-g")
                args.push("-Os")
                args.push("-w")
                args.push("-fno-exceptions")
                args.push("-ffunction-sections")
                args.push("-fdata-sections")
                args.push("-MMD")
                args.push("-mmcu=atmega328p")
                args.push("-DF_CPU=16000000L")
                args.push("-DARDUINO=152")
                args.push("-I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/cores/arduino/")
                args.push("-I/usr/lib/avr/include/avr/")
                args.push("-I/usr/lib/avr/include/")
                args.push("-I/usr/lib/avr/include/util/")
                args.push("-I/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants/standard/")
                args.push("-c")
                args.push(input.filePath)
                args.push("-o")
                args.push(output.filePath)
                var compilerPath = "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++"
                var cmd = new Command(compilerPath, args);
                cmd.description = 'compiling ' + input.fileName;
                cmd.highlight = 'compiler';
                cmd.silent = false;
                console.error(input.baseDir + '/' + input.fileName);
                return cmd;
            }
        }
        Rule {
                    multiplex: true
                    inputs: ['obj']
                    Artifact {
                        fileTags: ['elf']
                        filePath: project.name + '.elf'
                    }
                    prepare: {
                        var args = [];
                        args.push("-mmcu=atmega328p")

                        for (i in inputs["obj"])
                                    args.push(inputs["obj"][i].filePath);

                        args.push('-o');
                        args.push(output.filePath);
                        var compilerPath = "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++"
                        var cmd = new Command(compilerPath, args);
                        cmd.description = 'linking' + project.name;
                        cmd.highlight = 'linker';
                        return cmd;
                    }
                }
        Rule {
                    multiplex: true
                    inputs: ['elf']
                    Artifact {
                        fileTags: ['hex']
                        filePath: project.name + '.hex'
                    }
                    prepare: {
                        var args = [];
                        args.push("-O")
                        args.push("ihex")

                        for (i in inputs["elf"])
                                    args.push(inputs["elf"][i].filePath);

                        //args.push('-o');
                        args.push(output.filePath);
                        var compilerPath = "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy"
                        var cmd = new Command(compilerPath, args);
                        cmd.description = 'create hex' + project.name;
                        cmd.highlight = 'linker';
                        return cmd;
                    }
                }
        Rule {
            inputs: ['hex']
            Artifact {
                fileTags: ['comp']
                filePath: project.name + '.comp'
            }
            prepare: {
                var args =[];

                args.push ("-pm328p")
                args.push("-carduino")
                args.push("-P/dev/ttyUSB0")
                args.push("-b57600")
                args.push("-D")
                for (i in inputs["hex"])
                            args.push("-Uflash:w:" + inputs["hex"][i].filePath +":a");
                var flasher = "/usr/share/arduino/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude"
                var cmd = new Command(flasher, args);
                cmd.description = 'create micro ' + project.name;
                cmd.highlight = 'linker';
                return cmd;
            }
        }

}
```

вот main.c delay.h не подключается функция delay(1000) не объявлена

```
    #include "micro.h"
#include "delay.h"
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {

//  pinMode(led, 1);
}
int main()
{
    int x=1;

return x;
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
//  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)

  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
 // digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
//  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно подключить пути к стандартным библиотекам. Это можно сделать следующим образом:

```
cpp.includePaths: [
    "powercontroler/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F1xx/Include",
    "powercontroler/Drivers/CMSIS/Include",
    "powercontroler/Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc",
    "powercontroler/Drivers/STM32F1xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy",
    "powercontroler/Inc",
]
```

Пример приведен для STM32, но в случае avr решение будет таким же. Сам код пишется внутри Product, где-то между группами и правилами. 
Также рекомендую вам переписать процесс компилирования, создав правильный профиль Qt, и используя после этого модуль cpp:[Module cpp](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/cpp-module.html).

Используя его аппарат возможно менять/устанавливать флаги компиллятора, линкера и т.д. (то, что вы делаете в первом и втором Rule).

Рекомендую обратить внимание на ответ на вопрос: [qbs avr compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42366163/qbs-avr-compiling). В ответе показана правильная организация qbs файла именно для avr.